# Firebase Ionic 4 plugin

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, ionic4

I get the following error all the time:

```
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-firebase" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-firebase" for ios
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase': CordovaError: Uh oh!
File already exists at destination "/Users/alexcarrascosalvador/Documents/Projects/RACE/race-sos/platforms/ios/RACE SOS/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist" for resource file specified by plugin cordova-plugin-firebase in iOS platform
    at install (/Users/alexcarrascosalvador/Documents/Projects/RACE/race-sos/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/plugman/pluginHandlers.js:64:23)
    at ActionStack.process (/Users/alexcarrascosalvador/Documents/Projects/RACE/race-sos/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/ActionStack.js:56:25)
    at PluginManager.doOperation (/Users/alexcarrascosalvador/Documents/Projects/RACE/race-sos/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/PluginManager.js:114:20)
    at PluginManager.addPlugin (/Users/alexcarrascosalvador/Documents/Projects/RACE/race-sos/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/PluginManager.js:144:17)
    at Api.addPlugin (/Users/alexcarrascosalvador/Documents/Projects/RACE/race-sos/platforms/ios/cordova/Api.js:234:10)
    at handleInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:594:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:357:28
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-firebase" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Uh oh!
File already exists at destination "/Users/alexcarrascosalvador/Documents/Projects/RACE/race-sos/platforms/ios/RACE SOS/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist" for resource file specified by plugin cordova-plugin-firebase in iOS platform
```

I found it impossible to fix this error. I put my plugins in order to install Firebase first, but I still get this error when I try to install the plugin in the iOS platform. I also removed the platform and added it again and I still get the error. I deleted the whole project and downloaded again, installed the dependencies and build it, but I still get the `cordova-plugin-firebase` error...

Answer (score 0):

I had a chance to fix this issue and please follow the below steps.

1. Rename the file *GoogleService-Info.plist* in our root folder to *GoogleService-Info.plistxx*
2. Remove the file inside your *platform/ios/AppName/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist*
3. Run the command `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase`
4. Rename the file *GoogleService-Info.plistxx* in our root folder to *GoogleService-Info.plist*